# why here do we get 4 objects instead of 3? because I have only 3 elements in my list

Tags: python, for-loop, generator, iterable

why here do we get 4 objects instead of 3? because I have only 3 elements in my list

```
def special_for(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        try:
            # print(next(iterator))
            print(iterator)
            next(iterator)
        except(StopIteration):
            break


my_arr = [1, 2, 3]
special_for(my_arr)
```

And the output is :

```
<list_iterator object at 0x107a67e50>
<list_iterator object at 0x107a67e50>
<list_iterator object at 0x107a67e50>
<list_iterator object at 0x107a67e50>
```

Comment: The line `print(iterator)` will be executed 4th time before `next(iterator)` raise `StopIteration` error

Comment: The list contains integers and the script is printing out the same iterator (see the address in memory at 0x...). Look at what happens when you print out the result of next iterator and you should see the integers in the console. You have only three elements in the array but the algorithm calls print(iterator) 4 times before an exception raises cause the iterator has no more elements to retrieve from the iterable. It is preferable to use the ''for e in iterator'' loop syntax to avoid a construct with exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

The script prints the address of the iterator and not the elements of the iterable and this is done before calling `next`. `print` is then called four times before `next` that will raise an exception the fourth time it is called (iterator is then exhausted - pointing to nothing). Look at your console output, `print` prints out an address in the form of `0x...` and not the element itself.

Here is an example that prints out the elements of the iterable

```
def iter_and_print(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    while True:
            try:
                    print(next(iterator))
            except StopIteration:
                    break
iter_and_print([1, 2, 3])
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```